# Django - Test asynchronous method causes psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

Tags: python, django, postgresql, asynchronous, testing

I want to test some async method that I use on an async view, but I want to be very clear that right now I am not testing my view, I already saw the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#testing-asynchronous-code) on django but it is only for views....

So I have this class containing multiple method and even contacting database asynchronously.

```
class SessionService:
    """ Session service.

    Attributes:
            uuid (str): system uuid
            gcloud (str): console gcloud_id
            start (str): start time of the period
            end (str): end time of the period
    """

    def __init__(self, uuid: str, gcloud: str, start: str, end: str):
        self.system_uuid: str = uuid
        self.gcloud_id: str = gcloud
        self.start: str = start
        self.end: str = end

    @database_sync_to_async
    def __vision_data(self) -> Tuple[List[str], List[str], List[int]]:
        """ Async method to get vision module's data from a uuid

        Returns
        ----------
        QuerySet
            List where 1st element are gcloud id, 2nd UUID and last system IDs
        """
        return System.objects.get_vision_conf_data(self.system_uuid)

    @async_property
    async def __vision_system_ids(self) -> List[int]:
        """ get visions Ids

        Returns:
            List[int]
        """
        data = await self.__vision_data()
        return data[2]

    async def get_session_list(self) -> List[Dict[str, Union[str, bool, int]]]:
        """ Get all session for a period for a system
        Returns:
            List[Dict[str, Union[str, bool, int]]]
        """
        spraying_session: SprayingSessionSumUpGetter = SprayingSessionSumUpGetter(self.gcloud_id, self.start,
                                                                                  self.end)
        vision_systems_ids: List[int] = await self.__vision_system_ids
        sessions: List[Dict[str, Union[str, pd.Timestamp]]] = await spraying_session.get_sum_up(
            vision_systems_ids)
        return sessions
```

I have two different situations, with the same problem at the end.

**Situation ONE:**

I am now trying to test get_session_list. To do so, I use **TestCase from django.test** .

My tests inherite from another class because I need to set a System instance and it depends on A LOT of other table so I manage it on another test Class SystemSetUpTest So, I have:

```
class SystemSetUpTest(TestCase):
    @staticmethod
    def setUp():  # pylint: disable=too-many-locals
        create_everything_needed

    @staticmethod
    def tearDown():
        delete_all_stuff

class SystemServicesTest(SystemSetUpTest):
    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
```

this is the test causing issue:

```
async def test_getting_sessions_list(self):
    uuid: str = self.uuid

    console_gcloud_id = 'console'
    start_period = '2021-05-06'
    end_period = '2021-05-07'
    service = SessionService(uuid, console_gcloud_id, start_period, end_period)
    print(await service.get_session_list())
```

and this is the complete Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/systems/tests/test_set_up.py", line 60, in tearDown
    User.objects.filter(email="jul@gmail.com").delete()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 745, in delete
    collector.collect(del_query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 243, in collect
    new_objs = self.add(objs, source, nullable,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 107, in add
    if not objs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 284, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1167, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 236, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

Basically it can tearDown the database, we can see it from:

> File "/app/systems/tests/test_set_up.py", line 60, in tearDown
> User.objects.filter(email="jul@gmail.com").delete()

---

**situation TWO**
**class SystemServicesTest** inherit direclty from TestCase and I set up my system directly in it's setUp method,

then the stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 223, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 292, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/systems/tests/test_services.py", line 41, in test_getting_sessions_list
    print(await service.get_session_list())
  File "/app/systems/services/session.py", line 85, in get_session_list
    vision_systems_ids: List[int] = await self.__vision_system_ids
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/async_property/base.py", line 37, in get_value
    return await self._fget(instance)
  File "/app/systems/services/session.py", line 47, in __vision_system_ids
    data = await self.__vision_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 444, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 455, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asgiref/current_thread_executor.py", line 22, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/channels/db.py", line 13, in thread_handler
    return super().thread_handler(loop, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 486, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/systems/services/session.py", line 38, in __vision_data
    return System.objects.get_vision_conf_data(self.system_uuid)
  File "/app/systems/models/manager/manager.py", line 130, in get_vision_conf_data
    gcloud: List[str] = [data[0] for data in visions]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 140, in __iter__
    return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1124, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1167, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 237, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 236, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

The problem seems to come from:

> File "/app/systems/models/manager/manager.py", line 130, in
> get_vision_conf_data
> gcloud: List[str] = [data[0] for data in visions]

Here is the full method:

```
def get_vision_conf_data(self, system_uuid: str) -> Tuple[List[str], List[str], List[int]]:
    """ Get vision conf data for a system
    Parameters
    ----------
    system_uuid : str
        The system uuid
    Returns
    -------
    Tuple[List[str], List[str], List[int]]
        List[str]: List of all visions gcloud id
        List[str]: List of all visions uuid
        List[str]: List of all visions system_id
    """
    visions: QuerySet = self.get_queryset().get_vision_conf_details(system_uuid)

    gcloud: List[str] = [data[0] for data in visions]
    uuid: List[str] = [data[1] for data in visions]
    system_id: List[int] = [data[2] for data in visions]

    return gcloud, uuid, system_id
```

where get_vision_conf_details is a call to my db.

How should I test my class ?
Any help would be great ! thanks.

Comment: Hey @Kimor have you actually resolved this issue?

Comment: Hey, @BrianDestura, I had to modify my code so no. But I think the solution is to test the code synchronously.

Comment: I see thank you!